# How make useState effect only one item in a array using map method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I can have a array like this

```
const dayOfWeek = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tus", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
```

And i have a chip componet look like this

```
const DateItem = (props: DateItemProps) => {
  const { days, selected, setSelected } = props

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      row
      center
      onPress={() => {
        setSelected(!selected)
      }}
      style={!selected ? CONTAINER_WITHOUT_SELECTED : CONTAINER_WITH_SELECTED}
    >
      <Text style={!selected ? TEXT_WITHOUT_SELECTED : TEXT_WITH_SELECTED}>{days}</Text>
      {selected && <Icon name="check" color="white" />}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}

export default DateItem
```

I use useState hook to check if item was selected

```
 const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false)
```

And use this hook like this

```
<View row style={{ flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
            {dayOfWeek.map((item, index) => (
              <View>
                {console.log("index ", selected[index])}
                <DateItem days={item} selected={selected} setSelected={setSelected} />
              </View>
            ))}
          </View>
```

Problem is whenever i click an item, all item checked at same time, so how can i click one item, then all other item still not clicked? thank you

Here is when i click one item

[image]

Comment: You're passing the same boolean `selected` value to all your children, instead you should track an `id` or other unique property that you can compare against in the child.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState()
```

And in the map function:

```
<DateItem days={item} selected={selected === item} setSelected={setSelected} />
```

And in setSelected:

```
// instead of !selected
setSelected(item)
```

If instead you want to select multiple items, use an array of selected days in use state:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState([])
```

And in the map function:

```
<DateItem days={item} selected={selected.indexOf(item) !== -1} setSelected={setSelected} />
```

And in setSelected:

```
setSelected((previous) => {
  const temp = previous;
  // either add or remove the new item from temp with temp.push() and temp.slice()
  return temp;
})
```

Comment: if the answer works for you, please accept it so we can close this question. If you have any other question or concern let me know @CODEforDREAM

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of your `selected` state datatype is a boolean, so it's affect every `dateItem` components you have. Maybe it is better to change the `selected` state into array or number.

Here is an example if `selected` state data type is number

**selected state**

```
   const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null)
```

**parent component**

```
<View row style={{ flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
            {dayOfWeek.map((item, index) => (
              <View>
                
                <DateItem days={item} index={index} selected={selected} setSelected={setSelected} />
              </View>
            ))}
          </View>
```

**dateItem Component**

```
const DateItem = (props) => {
  const { days, selected, setSelected, index } = props

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      row
      center
      onPress={() => {
        setSelected(index)
      }}
      style={selected !== index ? CONTAINER_WITHOUT_SELECTED : CONTAINER_WITH_SELECTED}
    >
      <Text style={selected !== index ? TEXT_WITHOUT_SELECTED : TEXT_WITH_SELECTED}>{days}</Text>
      {selected === index && <Icon name="check" color="white" />}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}

export default DateItem
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but maybe you a little bit misunderstanding, your method will only can selected one, but in my case i can select multi and also can unselect

Comment: Oh that's alright, i just read your question and you said "how can i click one item, then all other item still not clicked" so the code was for this case.  anw, other answers seems providing for multiselect ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up individual states for each button.

The way your code is working now *all the buttons are handling the same state*, that is why whenever you click any of them the state changes for all of them.

A possible workaround would be to turn your state from a single boolean to an object of booleans, or even an array.

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState([false,false,false,false,false,false,false])
```

or even

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState([monday: false, tuesday: false,wednesday: false, thursday: false, friday: false, saturday: false, sunday: false])
```

And within your `.map()` you may use the `index` in order to change the desired value

Comment: Thank for your answer, i will try it

Answer (score 0):

Update your Main Component like:

```js
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState("")
  
  const dayOfWeek = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tus", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]

  return (
    <View row style={{ flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
            {dayOfWeek.map((item, index) => (
              <View>
                {console.log("index ", selected[index])}
                <DateItem days={item} selected={selected} setSelected={setSelected} />
              </View>
            ))}
    </View>  
    );
```

And DateTime.js like this:

```js
const DateItem = (props: DateItemProps) => {
  const { days, selected, setSelected } = props
  console.warn("selected: ", selected)
  console.warn("days: ", days)
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      row
      center
      onPress={() => {
        setSelected(days)
      }}
      style={!selected ? CONTAINER_WITHOUT_SELECTED : CONTAINER_WITH_SELECTED}
    >
      <Text style={!selected ? TEXT_WITHOUT_SELECTED : TEXT_WITH_SELECTED}>{days}</Text>
      {selected === days && <Icon name="check" color="white" />}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but i can't unselect anymore, but i appreciate your answer